# How can I diagnose authentication issues in a custom single tenant Teams app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC website. It is hosted in Azure and users are authenticated with AAD for our single tenant. I intend to make the website available in a Teams app, so that my coworkers can navigate to my website via the Teams Windows app and the mobile app.

- I follow these steps to integrate security in a web browser: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/5-exercise-add-auth
- I followed these directions to integrate security with Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso. I'm not sure that I did this correctly.

At this point, I can:

- Login with a web browser
- Login via Teams mobile app
- Load Teams in a web browser then load my app (not a use case that I need to support, but this worked and I was not prompted to login. I assume that I wasn't prompted to login because I was already logged in directly in another browser tab).

I cannot:

- Login via Teams Windows app -- This is my primary use case unfortunately.

When I try to login with the Teams application on Windows (using the same pages and forms as on mobile), the page just disappears. I'm not prompted with the usual Microsoft login page.

How can I diagnose the cause of the problem? I don't see any obvious errors reported in Teams. Is there any way to get access to the root error?

EDIT:

login.microsoftonline.com is reporting "Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service." I'm now aware of the SameSite changes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-handle-samesite-cookie-changes-chrome-browser?tabs=dotnet) and I've implemented the recommended SameSiteCookieManager code to address the SameSite issue.

I'm still running into the same issue. No exceptions or errors reported except that Teams does not accept cookies.

Comment: Could you please confirm are you adding WebApplicationInfo  in your  manifest. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#2-update-your-teams-application-manifest) for more info.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your thoughts. I do have the WebApplicationInfo added to the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

May have to break this down further, here's how I would decipher it.
First of all, you will have to figure out if the issue is with Teams or on the Auth side.

1. Figure out which line of code is executing last? You can debug or write to terminal/logs.
2. Do you see any exceptions? Ideally debuggers can help or you can add some code to catch any exception.
3. If it's failing before executing any code, do you see any http requests going out, you can use fiddler for this. See if you are seeing any error codes.
4. If you are using Windows then check Event Logs for any errors or exceptions for Teams App. Look at the Application logs.
5. Look out for Audit logs and sign in logs and check if you see any activity in your tenant when you run this app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor

Some other points would be to check if you can repro this with a sample app or a different user(elevated user). If there is any additional info do share.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I'll be able to dig into your ideas tomorrow and I'll make sure to follow up!

Comment: Hey @N2S. I finally got to test your ideas -- thanks again! The issue is that the Microsoft response to the OWIN authentication challenge is: "Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service." I'm hunting for how to enable cookies in the Windows Teams App now.

Comment: No luck. I'm not sure how login.microsoftonline.com knows that my browser (the native browser in Teams) isn't accepting cookies. I went down the SameSite rabbit hole, and that lead to a dead end -- implementing the recommended cookie managers did not introduce any change.